# Find a definite integral which represent $ \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{k}{n+k}}} $

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

Find a definite integral which represent $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{k}{n+k}}}.$$
I don't know how can I approach the question.
Is the answer $$\int_{0}^{1}{\sqrt\frac{x}{x+1}}dx\;?$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: oh sry cant I change the title?

Comment: Does it help if I tell you that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{k}{n+k}}= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\left(\frac{k}{n}-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\sqrt\frac{k/n}{1+k/n}}\;?$$

Comment: I have tried but i cannot find (b-a)/n, which fit into this equation, because the denominator is n+k and nominator is k

Comment: Yes, very helpful

Comment: @OvernightFYT If you succeed at finding the right integral, you can answer your own question. That is acceptable on this site.

Comment: Ok! I will write the answer when I have found it

Comment: I think I have got the answer, but I'm not sure if I'm correct or not

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Ok Thx! Help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it simply
\begin{align*}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{k}{n+k}}} 
 & = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{\frac kn}{1+\frac kn}}} 
\\ & = \int_0^1\sqrt{\frac x{1+x}}dx.
\end{align*}
Or, with more explanation, if the Riemann integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ exists, then it can be written as the limit

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(a+\frac{b-a}{n}\,k\right)\,\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right).$$

Using the above formula with $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac x{1+x}}$, $a=0$ and $b=1$ reveals that
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac x{1+x}}dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{\frac kn}{1+\frac kn}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{k}{n+k}}}.$$

Therefore, the limit of interest is simply the Riemann Sum of the integral $ \int_0^1\sqrt{\frac x{1+x}}dx$
.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{k}{n+k}}}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt\frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1+\frac{k}{n}}}}$$ when we sub $$x=\frac{k}{n}$$ as sum k from 1 to n
sum k from 1 to n
means $\frac kn$ sum from $\frac 1n$ to 1

So we have $$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}dx$$

Comment: It would be $\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac x{x+1}}dx$ ,since you have written integration. Isn't it?

Comment: Your reasoning is not quite rigorous.

Comment: how can I improve in the step